# Get array input and print the array (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, input, integer

I am writing a code that takes an array of 10 and collects user input. I want to print out the array after the user has finished putting all the values into it. The problem is that when I printout the array it gives me a bunch of garbage values and a weird output. I am not sure why it is doing what it is doing.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int num;

    int arr[10] = {0};

    cout<<"Enter 10 numbers: "<< endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cin>>arr[i];

        
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<< " ";
    }

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are running the loop from 0 till `sizeof(arr)`, here `sizeof(arr)` means the size of array in bytes. Which happens to be `sizeof(int)` times the number of elements in the array.

So if we consider `sizeof(int)` to be 4bytes(i.e. each int takes `4bytes` in memory), and number of elements to be 10, then it would be 4*10 = 40. So the `for` loop would run for 40 times.

Instead do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int num;

    int arr[10];

    cout<<"Enter 10 numbers: "<< endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])); i++){
        cin>>arr[i];

        
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])); i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<< " ";
    }

return 0;

}
```

As pointed out by @user4581301, it's better to make the loop stop taking input at `(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))`, as the size can be changed laterwards.

I have corrected it. It will work now.

Comment: Recommendation: Make the same change to `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`. Right now the input loop is vulnerable to changing `int arr[10];` to some number other than 10.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(arr)` is the total size in bytes of the array, not the number of elements. That's probably 40 rather than 10, Because the typical compiler targeting desktop PC hardware uses a 32 bit `int` at this time.

If your compiler's up to date and supports at least the C++17 Standard revision, use [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) to get the number of elements in the array, but a better option (supported back to C++11) is to use range-based for loops and let the compiler figure out the bounds for you. This makes changes to the count of elements in `arr` self-managing.

Eg:

```
for(auto & val:arr){
    cin>>val;
}
for(auto & val:arr){
    cout<<arr[i]<< " ";
}
```

If range-based `for` and `std::size` are not available, define and use a constant value everywhere you use 10 or `sizeof(arr)`.

Eg:

```
const int ARR_SIZE = 10;
```

and then the definition of `arr` becomes

```
int arr[ARR_SIZE] = {0};
```

and the control for both `for` loops become

```
for(int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
```

This allows you to vary the size of `arr` with only one change required to make the code function correctly. This is also less cumbersome than repeating `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` everywhere the number of elements in `arr` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are getting garbage values is very well explained in the other answers. You can use [`std::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) or [range-based for-loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) here for iterating through the array. C++ is smart enough to deduce the length of the array for you.

```
int main(){
    int arr[10]{0};

    /* Take inputs from the console and fill the array here. */

    auto start = std::begin(arr);
    auto end = std::end(arr);
    for(; start!=end; ++start)
        std::cout<<*start<<" ";

    // Or using range-based for-loop
    for(auto val: arr)
        std::cout<<val<<" ";
}
```